# Rust. Преобразования типов в конструкции `match`

Tags: winapi, rust

Есть перечисление клавиш внутри приложения:

```
enum Key {
    // Перечисление клавиш...
}
```

Нужно преобразовать в них поступающие сообщения ввода клавиатуры. Для этого используется следующая функция:

```
fn translate_key(wParam: WPARAM, lParam: LPARAM) -> Option<Key> {
    match wParam {
        // Первый случай:
        VK_BACK => Some(Key::Backspace),
        VK_TAB => Some(Key::Tab),
        // и т.д.

        // Второй случай:
        b'0' => Some(Key::Num0),
        b'1' => Some(Key::Num1),
        // и т.д.

        _ => None
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что wParam, константы VK_* и символы имеют разные типы. При попытке преобразовать их в выражении вроде `VK_*/b'*' as WPARAM => ...` компилятор не может распознать токен `as`.

Как решить эту проблему?

Заранее, спасибо!

**UPD:** Под `b'*'` я имею в виду любой допустимый символ: от '0'(0x30) до '9'(0x39) или от 'A'(0x41) до 'Z'(0x5A). Коды этих символов есть в списке [виртуальных кодов клавиатуры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx). Из него видно, что коды символов и коды других виртуальных клавиш между собой не пресекаются.

Прочитал совет ниже, переписал `match` под тип `i32`:

```
fn translate_key(wParam: WPARAM, lParam: LPARAM) -> Option<Key> {
    match (wParam as i32) { // wParam к типу i32
        // Первый случай (без изменений):
        VK_BACK => Some(Key::Backspace),
        VK_TAB => Some(Key::Tab),
        // ...

        // Второй случай (заменил символы на их коды):
        0x30 => Some(Key::Num0),
        0x31 => Some(Key::Num1),
        // ...
        0x39 => Some(Key::Num9),

        0x41 => Some(Key::A),
        0x42 => Some(Key::B),
        // ...
        0x5A => Some(Key::Z),

        _ => None
    }
}
```

Все работает. Думаю вопрос решен.

Comment: `as` не является валидной частью паттерн матчинга. Тебе нужно все варианты привести к одному типу, например `u8`. Будет что-то вроде: `match (wParam as u8) { ... }`.

Comment: Вам лучше сделать две отдельные функции для преобразования байтов и виртуальных кодов клавиш. Т.к. ASCII коды символов не всегда соответствуют виртуальным кодам клавиш. В частности `VK_* == 0x6A` и `b'j' == 0х6A`, а `b'*' == 0x2A`

Comment: @Wex, выделите из своего вопроса ответ и примите его (нажмите галочку). И будет хорошо, если укажете в нем авторов, которые Вам помогли.